# how to remove button space alocated for text drawableTop

Tags: android

[image]

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/abarprofile"/>



 <style name="DashboardButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
```

is there a way to make my icon wrap content?to take out the space below for text disregard the space on left and right i need those space for icon space between each other but i don't need space below and above image how can i take it out.i was able to take out the space above but i cant take out the space below how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the space at the bottom of the button using perfect height of button like
**android:layout_height="40dip"**

Lyaout Code

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/tvQuickContactCall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_call"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

Graphical Layout

[image]

Comment: one question mate what is the difference of using background color transparent to @null?

Comment: Yes there is difference in Transparent a alfa layer exist so we can increase and decrease the transparency but if we put @null it means there is not layer nothing.

Comment: But in my answer it should be not effected your problem you can set background either @null or transparent as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button that only contains an image (and no text), you should use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:src="@drawable/abarprofile"/>
```

Comment: i tried this one but i cant use my selector because im using button selector to make my button state work but thanks anyway the first one works just fine

Comment: @SatineKainne - button selectors for `ImageButtons` need to be on the `background`, rather than the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use margin such as

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dip"
/>
```

By doing this way, the negative sign actually remove the spaces by the button.